# Why does the homology of the this plain simplicial complex vanish?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I can't find a solution to the following exercise:

Let $K$ be a plain simplicial complex, which can be represented as a union of simplices
$\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$ (and their boundary simplices), such that for some integer $d \geqslant 2$ we have

$\operatorname{dim} \sigma_i \geqslant d$ for all $i$ and

for every $1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n$ the intersection $\sigma_i \cap \sigma_j$ has dimension at most $d − 2$.

Show that the homology of $K$ vanishes in dimension $d$ and above.

Could somebody eventually help me? If any definition is not clear, just ask me and I will give it to you.

Comment: Seems to me like a $\bowtie$ with its two faces could be such a $K$. Is this accurate?

Comment: Describe a $d$-cycle in this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Let me indicate the proof in the special case that $\text{dim} \, \sigma_i = d = 2$. Let's write out the boundary of each 2-simplex $\sigma_i$:
$$\partial \sigma_i = \tau_{i,0} - \tau_{i,1} + \tau_{i,2}
$$
where $\tau_{i,j}$ ($j=0,1,2$) is a simplex of dimension equal to $\text{dim}\sigma_i - 1 = 2=1 = 1$.

Your hypothesis implies that if $i \ne i'$ then $\tau_{i,j} \ne \tau_{i',j'}$ (no matter what $j$ and $j'$ are).

So, now consider a general 2-chain:
$$c = \sum_i {a_i} \sigma_i
$$
Taking the boundary we get
$$\partial c = \sum_i a_i (\tau_{i,0} - \tau_{i,1} + \tau_{i,2})
$$
To determine whether $c$ is a cycle, i.e. whether $\partial c = 0$, we must collect terms and see what cancellation there might be. *BUT*, there are no terms to collect because of the fact that $\tau_{i,j} \ne \tau_{i',j'}$ if $i \ne i'$. Therefore there is no cancellation at all. So if $c \ne 0$ then $\partial c \ne 0$.

The same proof works for cycles of any fixed dimension $\ge d$, the key point being that in the "collect terms and cancel" step, there is no cancellation at all because of the fact that $\tau_{i,j} \ne \tau_{i',j'}$ if $i \ne i'$.

Thus the cycle group in the chosen dimension is trivial, and so the homology group (cycles modulo boundaries) is also trivial.